# no single-int-arg constructor/factory method

Tags: jackson, fasterxml

I have this code:

```
final Person p = new Person(1L);
final ObjectMapper mapper = JacksonUtil.INSTANCE.getMapper();
final TypeReference<HashMap<String, Object>> typeMap = new TypeReference<HashMap<String, Object>>() {};
final String personJson= mapper.writeValueAsString(p);
mapper.readValue(personJson, typeMap);
```

`personJson` is like:

```
"id" : 1
```

Whenever I have a `Long type` in my Json, it doesn't work when I try to read it. I have this error:

> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not
>   instantiate value of type [simple type, class
>   org.codehaus.jackson.generated.java.lang.Number] from Integral number;
>   no single-int-arg constructor/factory method

How can I make it accept the type `Long`? Is there any feature to enable in the mapper?

Answer (score 5):

Create a constructor in Person that accepts an integer (and not a long as you do). If you definitely want to accept a long then try to create a constructor that accepts a Number.

Comment: Can you please give an example?

Answer (score 0):

Create a constructor in Person that accepts an integer (and not a long as you do). If you definitely want to accept a long then try to create a constructor that accepts a Number.
Suppose you have a bean/model class like this

```
public class Person{
    private Long id;
    private String name;

    public Person() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    public Person(Long id) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
    }

    //getter and setter
}
```

**Here second constructor accept an Long value**

I hope that your

> no single-int-arg constructor/factory method

error will be gone