# Change type of foreign key from java.net.URI to number - POST method

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have two models User, Task and TaskRepository, UserRepository associated with them. I am using Spring boot with spring-boot-starter-web and spring-boot-starter-data-rest packages.

```
@RepositoryRestResource(path="/task")
public interface TaskRepository extends CrudRepository<Task, Integer> {
}

@RepositoryRestResource(path="/user")
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Integer> {
}
```

When i want to save new task i have to pass a user. I noticed that he has to be passed as java.net.URI but this is really strange for me. Why can't it be just user id. It's possible to change this ?

Comment: Hi Dawid, could you please clarify a bit further on what you're trying to do? I'm assuming you have a database containing a `user` table and a `task` table, and you have two Entity classes (user and task) as well as their associated repository interfaces. I didn't quite get what you mean by, "When I want to save new task I have to pass a user." You're trying to create a new task, and there must be a user in the database to which you are going to assign that task, correct? So I'm assuming the user is being represented via some sort of varchar ID field? Can you also post the error/message?

Comment: ```Could not read document: Can not construct instance of pl.zadane.domain.User: no int/Int-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from Number value (1)\``` Spring boot accept only full rest url to object. for example http://localhost:8080/user/1 and this work but i want to be able to pass just 1. This is related to http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#_customizing_item_resource_uris but this seems to be complicated. This example in docs doesn't work for me

Comment: Let's say you have a REST service with a `user` entity, and it contains the following two fields for simplicity of example -- ID (integer, auto-generated id), username (varchar). You also have the associated repositories. You would insert a new user into this entity via a POST request, using JSON as follows (using curl in this case). curl -i -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"username":"dawid"}' localhost:8080/user

Comment: REST services must be accessed using endpoint URLs; that's their interface. JSON is typically the data format used for sending data to a REST API that is used as an interface for your backend database. Again, I'm not sure if this is the explanation you're looking for; let me know if this isn't exactly your question..

Comment: Also, take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31881975/no-single-int-arg-constructor-factory-method

Comment: This doesn't make sense for me. Imagine that i want to create SPA that uses this API. Using full url to object will be nightmare

Comment: Sorry about the late reply. Hmm.. Why do you think it would be a nightmare? Let's say you're using Angular (or just pure JS, doesn't really make a difference) -- you can have fields in your interface that correspond to the data that needs to be inserted, and you would only have to code in the URL a single time. Simply populate the fields with the appropriate data and do a POST request through JavaScript. If I understand your concern correctly, I don't think that's any concern at all... that's the standard way of doing these things.

Comment: It sounds to me like your problem is something different, though, and I may be misunderstanding. That error you're getting I think has to do with a type mismatch or something of that sort.

Comment: What happens if you create a constructor `User(int id) {...}`?

Comment: -1 You always have to use the full URL, because the server wouldn't know to which resource associate the request (unless it's the only resource). Since you're using spring, you could take advantage of HATEOAS and make your client discover the URLs, so you don't have to write them.

Comment: @Dawid, I think this is a classical [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You didn't describe what you are really trying to achieve and thus can't get good answers. Starting from stating the problem on a higher level might be useful such as "I want a REST API for such and such entities with such and such methods and I'm using such and such tools. Here is my code and it doesn't work as I want in this particular scenario. [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is typically very useful as well.

Comment: Do you really have to use the `@RepositoryRestResource` annotation? Can't you use controllers and map your requests to these repositories?

Answer (score 0):

So, your question is:

> Why the parameters need to be passed as a Java.net.URI?

Mkyong has given the answer as below:

> This is always advisable to encode URL or form parameters; plain form
>   parameter is vulnerable to cross site attack, SQL injection and may
>   direct our web application into some unpredicted output.
>
> For example, when a user enters following special characters, and your
>   web application doesn’t handle encoding, it will caused cross site
>   script attack. Please remember always encode the URL string and form
>   parameters to prevent all the vulnerability attacks.

### Resource Link:

https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-encode-a-url-string-or-form-parameter-in-java/

Comment: I like simplicity and flexibility. Argument about security doesn't convince me. Why ? because all modern frameworks has some kind of 'parisng' layer. The necessity of passing parameters by URL has impact on creating application that uses this API.